# Indexing keys with long string data in Mongodb

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I'm using mongodb with `mongo` ruby gem.

I have really long strings in a collection of millions of documents that I'm working with and I need to do lookups by the long string - this is very slow - takes around 5 seconds - which pointed me to index the key. When I try to index the corresponding key in mongodb I get error `key too large to index`. On reading [Mongodb docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#indexes), this is expected as there is a limit for index size - `The total size of an index entry, which can include structural overhead depending on the BSON type, must be less than 1024 bytes.`

One way to handle this is to split the key holding the log strings to smaller chew-able sizes less than 1024 bytes.

```
client[:longStrColl].find().each do |doc|
    strParts = {}
    str = doc[:longStr]
    strParts = str.scan(/.{1,1024}/) # split into parts of max 1024 and min 1 chars
    strParts.each_with_index do |val, index|
        strParts["str#{index}"] = val;
    end
    client[:longStrColl].update_one({"_id" => doc["_id"]},doc.merge(strParts))
end
```

This gives the `longStr` split into 2 keys with max length of 1024 as below so that [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#index-type-compound) could be done on them for faster lookup.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6c634dd0ae362168c8fd58"),
    "longStr" : "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",
    //other key: values 
    "str0" : "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",
    "str1" : "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"
}
```

The issue I'm facing is even with this my index creation is failing with error `key too large to index`

```
db.longStrColl.createIndex( { str0: 1, str1: 1});
```

How do I go about splitting the strings correctly and indexing them ?

Comment: Have you considered using $text index:?

Comment: why do you require such long keys?

Comment: @maxpleaner - that's part of the data that's coming in on which I do not have control - I need to keep them so as to lookup by key value.

Comment: What I was getting at, is to say that maybe you can use a hash function to reduce the length of the keys. It wont 100% guarantee that unique keys remain unique but the chance of a,hash collision would be very unlikely

Comment: @maxpleaner - could you suggest how to go abt it ..

Comment: Look at the object hash method https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-hash